# GWT Celltable only displaying 15 rows

Tags: java, gwt

I'm having an issue where our cell table is only displaying 15 rows. I have something like the following:

```
//assume these are initialised correctly in the constructor
private final CellTable<DataModel> dataTable; 
private DataModel dataModel;

private void initialize(){
    dataTable.setRowData(0, data.getDataList());
    dataTable.setRowCount(data.getDataList().size());
}
```

Now `getDataList()` returns a `List<Data>` object which has a size of 18, but for some reason it only displays 15.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there some "Gotcha" for celltables that restrict the number of rows it will display?

As a side note, when I sort the list I can see all of the data objects but only 15 at a time...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`CellTable`, by default, shows 15 items per page](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html#CellTable()).

Call [`setVisibleRange`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractHasData.html#setVisibleRange(int,%20int)) to change the rows that the `CellTable` displays. See the [Cell Table Developer's Guide](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable.html) for more details.

Comment: Really don't know how I could have missed that but Thanks very much!

Comment: I missed it and this answer helped me.

Answer (score 3):

I always use the code below passing my `CellTables`/`CellLists` when I don't want pagination. Basically, you have to adjust your `setVisibleRange` to the list size. And this method does that automatically when you change the list size.

```
public static void setupOnePageList(final AbstractHasData<?> cellTable) {
    cellTable.addRowCountChangeHandler(new RowCountChangeEvent.Handler() {
        @Override
        public void onRowCountChange(RowCountChangeEvent event) {
            cellTable.setVisibleRange(new Range(0, event.getNewRowCount()));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also instantiate the CellTable with the page size as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
    dataTable.setPageSize(100);
```

or put the page size you want

Comment: Why did you down voted this answer? setPageSize is a valid API call. Please, explain.